# So, captain Nares shipping company and Dodds/Pinkerton have signed a shipping charter agreeing to delayed payment post salvage profits

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology, style

[Related: Link to StackE Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25727/meaning-of-my-ownersll-have-to-rank-with-the-rest-on-their-charter-party)

> The ill-omened Flying Scud was abandoned and wrecked at Midway Atoll by its unscrupulous owners who conspired to commit an insurance fraud (In the process they murder a crew member). The conspiracy involved falsely loading it with silk bales (in fact dummy cloth not silk) and possible contraband opium.
> The partnership of Loudon Dodd & Jim Pinkerton aims to make a profit from salvaging wrecked ships and bid to purchase this wreck particularly as they (deviously) hoped to profit from hoped for contraband opium from the Flying Scud.
>
> Dodd & Pinkerton charter the company that employs Captain Nares & his ship Nora Creina & crew for its use to locate and salvage the Flying scud after winning bidding for it at auction. So, captain Nares shipping company and Dodds/Pinkerton have signed a shipping charter agreeing to delayed **payment post salvage profits**.

The wording of this sentence of the answer #2, line 14 on StackExLiterature looks like a juridical phrasing. Especially the passage *post salvage profits* seems to be kind of juridical style or terminology, right? What does it mean exactly (that is juridically)?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "juridical" but commercialese/legalese.  I assume they're agreeing to delay payment until they've liquidated what they've managed to salvage (and possibly have deducted certain salvage costs).  The statement doesn't indicate who the payor and payee are.

Comment: To me *post salvage profits* sounds like *net of taxes* or *after tax (deduction)*, certainly not literal but stylistic.

Comment: "delayed payment / post  / salvage profits". Post as in afterwards (c.f. *post meridiem*). They'll get paid when the loot has been sold.

Comment: Aside: by 'juridical style' do you mean 'judicial style'? And 'juridically / judicially'.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with taxes but with turning a profit on what has been salvaged. Presumable Nares is assuming some degree of risk by not charging for the use of his ship up front.

Comment: Definitely no taxes! From salvaged contraband?

Comment: @ Weather Vane - I don't see much difference between *juridical* and *judicial* but maybe you are right :). **"Definitely no taxes! From salvaged contraband" :))**

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juridical%2Cjudicial&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) compares the usage of juridical and judicial.

Comment: It's part of an answer to your own question. Why don't you ask the person who wrote it what they meant?

Comment: . . . because this is a language question not a literature one, right?